# AWS Instance Suddenly Not Available in Browser - SSH and ping work

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ip

I am very new AWS and sys admin so bear with me...

I noticed my website was suddenly down today and have been working to sniff out the issue. No site files were changed as far as I am aware.  Here is what I have checked:

It was working fine until today, so it isn't a DNS issue but I double checked.

SSH works fine

Rebooted the instance - no change

Security Group Settings fine - port 80 and 443 open (site is SSL secured)

Tried adding ALL ICMP 0.0.0.0/0 for testing - pinging started working, still no browser response

Tried various iptable commands noted in other similar posts (not that I understand them) to no effect

I am at a loss and appreciate any assistance with locating and correcting the issue.

Here are the instance details:

Public DNS: ec2-54-213-52-95.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Public IP: 54.213.52.95

Instance ID: i-f331b5fe

Comment: Is the httpd service running ?

Comment: I tried restarting it and it came back as follows:   

sudo service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

I am really new to all this so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: This sounds more like a httpd issue than AWS. Have you checked error logs to see if there is an indication why it failed? Checked that existing httpd processes are running? Host memory, CPU, and disk space are fine? Finally, tried killing existing httpd processes if they are hung up so you can restart the process and open the listening socket again?

Comment: Yes, the httpd process was hung up.  Thanks for the tip!